# Delphi, problem with export to Excel dates lower 01.01.1900 OleException(800A03EC)

Tags: excel, delphi

The application has export to Excel. When the data has dates below 30.12.1899 it raise an error OleException(800A03EC). I know that the Excel stores dates as number and number 1 equals date 01.01.1900. But, in the Excel app I can set cell format as date and put in date below 01.01.1900. For example, the date 01.01.1798 doesn't cause an error or a warning.
For export we use ranges, for example:

```
var
  xlApp, xlWorkBook, xlWorkSheet, Range, Data: Variant;
begin
  xlApp := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    xlApp.Visible := False;
    xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook := 1;
    xlApp.Application.WorkBooks.Add;
    xlWorkSheet := xlApp.ActiveSheet;
    Range := xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1]];
    Range.NumberFormat := 'dd.mm.yyyy';
    Range.Value := StrToDate('01.01.1753');
    xlApp.Visible := True;
    xlApp.Quit;
  except
    xlApp.Visible := True;
  end;
```

Is there a way to awoid this error and put dates below 01.01.1900 in cell?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre], so we can easily test it ourselves.

Comment: I've included example which reproduce error.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I was about to write you my findings, which are negative, can not do, when I saw that you already got an answer, with which I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel doesn't support date values earlier than 01/01/1900. If in Excel itself you format a cell as dd.mm.yyyy then enter 01.01.1753, it will be stored as text (you can verify this by passing it to the `DATEVALUE` function, or attempting to add 1 to it). You can also replicate your Delphi error with a VBA macro - declare a `Date` variable, assign it to `DateSerial(1753, 1, 1)`, the try to assign a cell to it.